# keystone without any database?

Tags: keystonejs, keystone

after I setup keystone I run it using node keystone. Here I received error that I have to set up a db. I don't wan't any thing like that. I'm going to save all my data in a multi-chain server. how can I instruct that I don't need a data base connection and run node keystone.

Answer (score 0):

KeystoneJS requires MongoDB, it's a prerequisite for creating a Keystone project.

I'm unsure what you mean by "multi-chain server", but it doesn't sound like KeystoneJS is the right tool for you.